# Bluez BLE Connections Monitoring using DBUS-Python

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I was able to advertise the BLE and setup GATT Services and Characteristics by following the "[example_advertisement](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement)" and "[example-gatt-server](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server)" in [Bluez Examples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test). How can I know from DBUS when a BLE client is connected and when it is disconnected, using similar DBUS binding for Python? Which DBUS API do I look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another example that you can look at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-discovery

When BlueZ/DBus learns of a new remote device, then the InterfacesAdded signal gets sent.
When a remote device goes from disconnected, to connected. Then that is a property change on the device and the PropertiesChanged signal gets sent.
This is why there is the code in the above example they use add_signal_receiver to add callbacks for both signals.

```py
    bus.add_signal_receiver(interfaces_added,
            dbus_interface = "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager",
            signal_name = "InterfacesAdded")

    bus.add_signal_receiver(properties_changed,
            dbus_interface = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
            signal_name = "PropertiesChanged",
            arg0 = "org.bluez.Device1",
            path_keyword = "path")
```

As a side note, the DBus bindings used in the Buez examples are not the only ones available:
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/

Comment: Thank you, @ukBaz. The org.bluez.Device1 is the one I was looking for.

Comment: To monitor the disconnected, signal "InterfacesRemoved" is to be monitored.

Comment: `InterfacesRemoved` is when a device gets removed from the known list. When a device discsonnects, it will be a `PropertiesChanged` signal with the [Connected](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt#n174) property changing on the `org.bluez.Device1` interface