python-dbus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Cannot access system DBUS over Python on Linux
I am trying to create a Python script that I can run as a user systemd service on a Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. The script's purpose is to listen to system DBUS messages coming from BlueZ in order to notice connection/disconnection events from bluetooth devices.
The script works fine when I run it as sudo, but when I run it without, I get the following error message:
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: rejected attempt to call AddMatch by connection :1.117 (uid=1000 pid=1811 comm="python connect_listener.py") with uid 1000

I don't know if the following might be related, but when I run dbus-monitor --system in the terminal, I also get this warning, however the monitoring itself works:
dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: "rejected attempt to call BecomeMonitor by connection :1.118 (uid=1000 pid=1829 comm="dbus-monitor --system") with uid 1000". Falling back to eavesdropping.

The Python 3 script looks like this:
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
import dbus
from gi.repository import GLib
import dbus.mainloop.glib

def msg_cb(bus, msg):
    ...
    [callback stuff]
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    string = "interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged',eavesdrop='true'"
    bus.add_match_string(string)
    bus.add_message_filter(msg_cb)

    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
    mainloop.run()

What I tried so far
I assumed it has to do with the rights assigned to the pi user regarding listening on the system DBUS, so I tried fixing that. I found this thread and added a .conf file under /etc/dbus-1/system.d/ with this content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
   <policy user="pi">
      <allow eavesdrop="true" />
      <allow eavesdrop="true" send_destination="*" />
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring"/>
   </policy>
</busconfig>

I also wrote this into /etc/dbus-1/system-local.conf in case the previous was being overwritten by other .conf files, as I read that theis file is the last one being read in. I also made sure that the files end with .conf, as pointed out in this thread.
Finally, I also found this issue and made sure the pi user is a member of the bluetooth group.
I am very thankful for any help or input. It's probably something minor that I just don't know about.

If you want to monitor BlueZ connections and disconnections then using the BlueZ API is the correct way to do this. That does not require you to run with sudo. More information at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62959014/7721752 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63635759/7721752

More than that, signals are typically broadcast in the first place, so there should never be need to use monitoring or eavesdrop=true for them... How did you arrive at this code?

I ended up finding this RPi forum thread through the links provided by @ukBaz. The btminder script provided there works perfectly, it uses add_signal_receiver instead of the match string.
To @user1686: I derived the initial way with the match string from this Stackoverflow post.
